# Set the max attribute of a input box from the value of another one dynamically html

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I am trying to set the max quantity of this input box to another input box but I am missing something on how to connect the two of them. Here is the one that I want the max value to change based no the current value of another input

```
<input id="movement-quantity" class="movement-quantity" type="number" step="1" min="0" max = "1" pattern="\d*" required>
```

This is the input that I want to get the value from, this value will automatically change wit other code so I am trying to listen to this one

```
<input id="store-from-current-quantity" class="store-from-current-quantity" type="text" disabled>
```

Here is the function that I am using currently

```
    function getMaxValueForRequest()
{
    var requester = document.getElementById("movement-quantity");
    var currentItemAmount = parseInt(document.getElementById("store-from-current-quantity").value);
    requester.max = currentItemAmount;
}
```

And this is at the start of the script file that the function above is in

```
//variables
var numberAv=  parseInt(document.getElementById("store-from-current-quantity").value);
numberAv.elX.onchange = getMaxValueForRequest;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

**Notes**

- I've manually given `#store-from-current-quantity` has a value in the HTML - I assume this is being set elsewhere in your app.
- The `change` event listener does not fire until blur/submit/etc, so you may want to consider `keydown` or `keyup`.

I have some confusion about `numberAv.elX.onchange` however - why are you trying to get `elX` property of a Number?

I've removed the `disabled` attribute on the second input in this example to you can test it.

```js
function getMaxValueForRequest() {
  var requester = document.getElementById("movement-quantity");
  var currentItemAmount = parseInt(document.getElementById("store-from-current-quantity").value);
  requester.setAttribute('max', currentItemAmount);
}


// init once to set
getMaxValueForRequest()


// listen for changes
document.getElementById("store-from-current-quantity").addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  getMaxValueForRequest()
})
```

```html
<input id="movement-quantity" class="movement-quantity" type="number" step="1" min="0" max = "1" pattern="\d*" required>
<input id="store-from-current-quantity" class="store-from-current-quantity" type="text" value="5">
```

Comment: Should all of these be inside the same script tag right?

Comment: @MNM Kind of a silly question but sure, as long as `getMaxValueForRequest` is defined first.

Comment: Im sorry I was putting it in the wrong file. this was kind of dumped on me and I don't know js or html, learn as I go. Thank you very much it works and is a lot nicer than what I was doing. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The following Snippet demonstrates how to sync input 1's value to input 2's `max` attribute by using:

1. [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)
2. [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

#### SNIPPET

```js
var in1 = document.getElementById('in1');

in1.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var in2 = document.getElementById('in2');
  var out = document.getElementById('out');
  var val = parseInt(in1.value, 10);
  in2.setAttribute('max', val);
  out.value = in2.getAttribute('max');
}, false);
```

```html
<form id='f1' name='f1'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Sync Input1 Value to Input2 Max</legend>
    <label>Input 1:
      <input id='in1' name='in1' type='number'>
    </label>
    <label>Input 2:
      <input id='in2' name='in2' type='number' max=''>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label>Input 2 max="
      <output id='out' name='out'></output>"</label>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```